# Sum of single summation to double summation

Tags: summation, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a equation, $f(U)=\sum_{k=1}^pb_{1k}A_{k1}U_1+\sum_{k=2}^pb_{1k}A_{k2}U_2+...+\sum_{k=p}^pb_{1k}A_{kp}U_p$

How can I convert it into double summation $\sum\sum$, how to set the limit?

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

$f(U)=\sum_{t=1}^p\sum_{k=t}^pb_{1k}A_{kt}U_t$

Semantically this is the same as:

$f(U)=\sum_{t=1}^p(\sum_{k=t}^pb_{1k}A_{kt}U_t)$

(assuming you missed  $\ \dots\ $ in your sum)

So for $t=1$ we have:  $\sum_{k=1}^pb_{1k}A_{k1}U_1$
Then for $t=2$ we have:  $\sum_{k=2}^pb_{1k}A_{k2}U_2$
and so on.

Comment: Can you do a little detail? because if I break it down it doesn't go to the equation I wrote.

Comment: What doesn't go exactly? Do you have dots ($...$) after your second term? Also, do you really have $b_{1k}$ in every term of your sum?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited, it does have the dots. But can you show that If I convert the double sum into single some, how it comes the same equation?

Comment: Just replace the $t$ subsequently with $1,2,3,...,p$ and you will see what you get.

Comment: But can we put both limit at once?

Comment: I am not sure what that question means. I added some clarifications.

Comment: As your wrote $f(U)=\sum_{t=1}^p\sum_{k=t}^pb_{1k}A_{kt}U_t$ so if I break it,

$f(U)=\sum_{t=1}^p[b_{1t}A_{tt}U_t+...+b_{1p}A_{pt}U_p]$

$f(U)=\sum_{t=1}^pb_{1t}A_{tt}U_t+...+\sum_{t=1}^pb_{1p}A_{pt}U_p$

So it's not the same, not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you writing the inner sums in details? You had them written in summed form in the original expression. Why are you writing them in details now? Also, the outer sum symbol doesn't work this way, you can't just take it and apply it to every term. It's a sum of sums that we have here.